# How can I prevent gedit from pre-filling highlighted text in Ctrl+F/find?

Tags: gedit

is it possible to disable the auto populate the find box with currently selected text functionality when you press Control+F to find something. it really annoys me overwriting what i have in the find box making me have to type what i already had in it back in all the time.

if i wanted to change the content of the find box i would click it and past something in, it realty annoys me jumping to conclusions that it knows what i might want to do.

and even better would be to stop the find box from disappearing again if i dear to click somewhere in the text editor, but then that would just be nice to have, its the overwriting what i wrote in the box that relay annoys me.

Edit:
a year later and this is still the most irritating functionality i have had to use in any program. please anyone, is there any way to disable the CTRL+F box opening with whatever text was highlighted at the time you press CTRL+F. you can call it a feature all you like, i just wish there was some way to disable it, it drives me up the wall, if you open the find box and press "paste" it adds the clipboard content to the end of the string that should not even be in the search dam box,

Comment: If it really annoys you, don't pre-select any text when using control+f.

Comment: i copy text and jump to locations to past it back in, its relay annoying having to remember to un-sellect everything before pressing control+F

Comment: Copy text to clipboard, click ONCE to unselect the text, then hit control-f. Real easy. The problem that you discuss is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: this is still the most irritating fetcher i have ever seen implemented in any ubuntu application, please, is there any way i can disable the dam past clipboard into the Find search box without me asking it to copy paste anything anywhere.

Comment: yes if i new how i would love to, i like ubuntu, i don't own any windows computers any more, they are all Linux or Android, i have a reasonable programming knowledge from programming stepper motors and milling machines but i have never found time to do much with Linux or ubuntu.